# Alert on unsuccessful login in springboot and javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-boot, post, controller

I want to determine if my login was successful or not using a spingboot Controller, the problem is that whenever the login is unsuccessful i get a page with html -> false, seems like that javascript can't run `failure: funcion()...etc`. I tried even using `async: false` but nothing changed.

This is my Auth class in controller package. I tried even mapping doLogin method with @ResponseBody but it only shows response in a new page encoded in a JSON. If I remove the @ResponseBody tag it will give an error saying that a Boolean is not supported as a response.

```java
@Controller
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")
public class Auth {

    @GetMapping ("/login")
    public String login(){
        return "loginPage.html";
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    @RequestBody
    public Boolean doLogin(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse, @RequestParam String nickname, @RequestParam String password){
        System.out.println(nickname);
        System.out.println(password);

        User user = DBManager.getInstance().getUserDao().findByPrimaryKey(nickname);
        if(user != null) {
            httpRequest.getSession().setAttribute("User", user);
            try {
                httpResponse.sendRedirect("http://localhost:4200/");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @GetMapping ("/register")
    public String register() {
        return "registerPage.html";
    }

    @PostMapping ("/register")
    public void doRegister(@RequestParam String nickname){

        System.out.println(nickname );
    }
}
```

This is my Javascript linked to Login Button.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  const button = document.getElementById("submitButton");
  const nickname = document.getElementById('nicknameInput');
  const password = document.getElementById('passwordInput');

  button.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/doLogin',
      data: {'nickname': nickname.nodeValue, 'password': password.nodeValue},
      success: function(response){
        alert(response);
      },
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

What I'm trying to do is:

-> if login successful => redirect to Angular homepage maybe through javascript

-> if login unsuccessful => show an alert/label saying that there was an error

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Your Java controller only takes action on one condtion (there is a user in the DB) - but, if there is not a user in the DB, your code does nothing. You need to take _some_ action for the _other_ condition.

Comment: @RandyCasburn if there is not a user in DB it will return false, that what's i'm expecting, I want to capture that 'false' with javascript but I'm not able to print 'response' on an alert because I get an error saying that it doesn't accept a boolean or it only shows 'false' on a blank page. If there is a user it will redirect to angular homepage so I don't need to know response in that case.

Comment: Oh, I see. Change `@RequestBody` annotation to `@ResponseBody` - you don't need `@RequestBody` on the function and you don't need it specifically because you are not auto-deserializing the model. You may still run into issues with returning the Boolean object as a ResponseBody, but let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much I really didn't see that I mispelled the tag, anyway I will update this question with my solution, maybe it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

After some hours I found a solution even if I'm not able to figure out what was the real problem. Anyway, I tried to divide the Controllers into separate classes in java. One with tag `@Controller`, the other with tag `@RestController`.

```
@RestController
public class Auth {

    @PostMapping("/doLogin")
    @ResponseBody
    public String doLogin(HttpServletResponse response,@RequestParam String nickname, @RequestParam String password){
        System.out.println(nickname);
        System.out.println(password);

        User user = DBManager.getInstance().getUserDao().findByPrimaryKey(nickname);
        if(user != null){
            if(user.getPassword().equals(password)){
                return "Logged In";
            }else{
                return "Password is incorrect";
            }
        }else{
            return "Can't find user" + nickname;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the other class that is only for routing the appropriate HTML page.

```
@Controller
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")
public class PagesController {

    @GetMapping ("/login")
    public String login(){
        return "loginPage.html";
    }


    @GetMapping ("/register")
    public String register() {
        return "registerPage.html";
    }

}
```

And this is my javascript call with jQuery v3

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      let name = document.querySelector("#nicknameInput");
      let pass = document.querySelector("#passwordInput");
        $('#submitButton').click(function () {
          if(name.value !== undefined && pass.value !== undefined) {
            $.post('/doLogin',   // url
                    {nickname: name.value,
                    password: pass.value}, // data to be submit
                    function (data, status, jqXHR) {// success callback
                      $('p').append('status: ' + status + ', data: ' + data);
                    });
          }
        });
    });
  </script>
```

Hope this will help someone.